# Find if a class object is in an array/list

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have an array of

```
g = ['hi']
```

Then

```
'hi' in g
```

returns `True`.

What if I put an instantiated class into an array.

```
g.append(MyClass())
```

How do I find if the array contains an object of this class.

```
MyClass in g
```

returns `False`

Answer (score 3):

use `isinstance()` and `any()`:

```
In [95]: class A:pass

In [96]: lis=[A()]

In [97]: any(isinstance(x,A) for x in lis)
Out[97]: True

In [98]: lis=[1,2,3]

In [99]: any(isinstance(x,A) for x in lis)
Out[99]: False
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
MyClass in [type(x) for x in g]
```

This will only find objects whose *exact type* is `MyClass`; it will not find objects of a class derived from `MyClass`.  To do that, try one of the other answers that makes use of `isinstance()`.

Example:

```
>>> class Foo(object): pass
...
>>> g = [1, 2, Foo(), 4]
>>> g
[1, 2, <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f59552ef750>, 4]
>>> Foo in [type(x) for x in g]
True
```

Comment: use a generator expression for short-circuiting :  `Foo in (type(x) for x in g)`

Answer (score 1):

```
any(isinstance(x, MyClass) for x in g)
```